# proper configuration of /etc/network/interfaces for WOL, dhcp, bind, tftpboot, nfs servers

Tags: ubuntu, networking

This is my configuration of network interfaces, but i will its buggy. Could You show me which things of it should i avoid and how to correct them?

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


#external eth0 we get connection to sky from normal router here
auto enp0s10
iface enp0s10 inet static
        address 192.168.1.106
        gateway 192.168.1.1
        mtu 1500 #rise size of packet
        metric 100 #smaller priority for route -n, probably something else i forgot
        dns-nameservers 10.10.1.1
        up ethtool -s enp0s10 wol g #wake on lan
        pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/network/iptables.rules # rules for acting as router
        up ifdown enp0s10 --ignore errors #to restart ifconfig settings
        up ifup enp0s10 --ignore errors

#internal eth1 this is for private lan
allow-hotplug enp1s10
iface enp1s10 inet static
        address 10.10.1.1
        network 10.10.1.0
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.106
        broadcast 10.10.0.255
        mtu 7152
        dns-nameservers 10.10.1.1
        metric 0
        up ethtool -s enp1s10 wol g
        up ifdown enp1s10 --ignore-errors
        up ifup enp1s10 --ignore-errors
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have gotten neck-deep into something you don't seem to know much about, and seem to be trying to copy/paste a bunch of random bits you've found elsewhere.  Lets start with a crash-course in what it is you're asking about vs. what it is you posted.

WoL is a feature controlled by the BIOS.  It MUST be enabled in the BIOS first.  A network card can then generate the appropriate event that the BIOS will see, and cause a power-on/wake-up condition.

DHCP's job is solely to provide network configuration information automatically... so adding a bunch of static information in the interfaces file is just not right.

BIND is a DNS server.  I don't see anything you've posted relate to BIND in any way.

TFTPBoot is a method for a BIOS to use a network card to boot from a remote file historically located on a tftp server.  In modern configurations TFTP is no longer required (or desirable).  I also see nothing in your config relating to it.

NFS Servers... are servers configured with NFS (Network File System)  Machines configured to do PXE booting can use NFS for booting into more complex OSes.

Interface files, are used to configure network interfaces in an already running operating system.  An interface file does not care how the OS got booted.  The stuff you asked about above mostly assumes that your OS hasn't loaded yet... or you're in the process of (re)loading an operating system onto a device... or... attempting to boot a thin-client device.

You seem to be asking how to build an airplane, but only showing us a picture of the yoke.

Comment: relating to my second answer, I use this interfaces to use server with two interfaces as router for my lan. Im doing ifup/ifdown so that resolv.conf will be properly generated with dns-nameserver of my lan, so then master can ping to lan too. I need to use ethtool to setup WOL bcos sometimes WOL dont work without it. I made this configuration on trial and errors, im not from networking backgroud, just want to know how to setup diskless cluster of few old PC.